# improve response time for `Sound`

Tags: sound

Is it possible to improve response time for the keys of [this piano keyboard](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PianoKeys/#popup1)? As far as I understand, the bottleneck comes at `EmitSound[Sound[SoundNote[StringJoin[note, ToString[oct]]]]]`

Comment: When I download the cdf and run it on my local computer, the response is fine.